# Connecting databricks notebook to Appinsights in python code

Tags: azure-notebooks

Our databricks notebook is trigerred via an adf pipeline. I would like to add logging in my python notebook and would like to connect that logging information to be viewed in appinsights. How do I achieve that in python? Any pointers code examples would help

Answer (score 0):

To send logging information from your Databricks notebook to Azure Application Insights, you can use the `OpenCensus Python library` and `logger`.

Below is a sample code snippet to **configure the logger in your notebook**:

```py
   import logging
   from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

   # Replace with your Application Insights instrumentation key
   instrumentation_key = "<your_instrumentation_key>"

   logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
   logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(connection_string=f"InstrumentationKey={instrumentation_key}"))
```

Please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python) for details and examples.

Comment: OpenCensus is deprecated. How do we do the same with OpenTelemetry?